# Date format worldwide in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, international, cell-format

On a Mac Mountain Lion, US locales, I'm working on a Spreadsheet with macros like

```
TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&" is the date"
```

The problem is that the sheet is also used on computers set with French locale, where the macro expects

```
TEXT(TODAY(), "aaaa-mm-jj")&" is the date"
```

and displays `#VALUE` (since *a* is for *annee/year* and *j* is for *jour/day* in French, not *y* and *d*).

Is there a way - macro style - to make this "yyyy-mm-dd" format more international, or to force Excel to use the "ymd" format even on a Mac using French locale?

(if possible doing this in the same cell, ie without adding a new cell having a date inside then referenced in the displayed cell, since I want to modify the sheet as less as possible)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem ; here is the answer posted to my request [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/having-problems-with-text-formula-ddmmyyyy-format/1af25c4b-663f-4b95-8928-1e8d69f0727e?rtAction=1386269354609)

```
====================================
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Application
    Select Case .International(xlDateOrder)
        Case 0   'mdy
            ThisWorkbook.Names("DateFormat").Value = _
                .International(xlMonthCode) & _
                .International(xlDateSeparator) & _
                .International(xlDayCode) & _
                .International(xlDateSeparator) & _
                .International(xlYearCode) & _
                    .International(xlYearCode)

        Case 1  'dmy
            ThisWorkbook.Names("DateFormat").Value = _
                .International(xlDayCode) & _
                .International(xlDateSeparator) & _
                .International(xlMonthCode) & _
                .International(xlDateSeparator) & _
                .International(xlYearCode) & _
                    .International(xlYearCode)

        Case 2 'ymd
            ThisWorkbook.Names("DateFormat").Value = _
                .International(xlYearCode) & _
                    .International(xlYearCode) & _
                .International(xlMonthCode) & _
                .International(xlDateSeparator) & _
                .International(xlDayCode)
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

You just have to define the name "DateFormat" in the workbook, then use it in formulas as  =TEXT(A1,DateFormat)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I've just written my own user-defined function as

```
Public Function DATE_FORMAT(dt as Date, fmt as String) as String
    DATE_FORMAT = Format(dt, fmt)
End Function
```

It uses the fact that VBA works with US locale at all times, so I can always use `D` and `M` and `Y` as part of my format string.

You can then use the Excel formula `=DATE_FORMAT(A1, "YYYYMMDD")` even in non-US/UK locales.